# how to convert an app from plists to core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I have a sample app using CoreData, and am now ready to convert my existing app from using plists to now use Core Data.

My question is, does anyone know of a definitive to-do list of things to complete in order to make the conversion easy, thorough, and clean?

Comment: Your question kind of implies that this is a common procedure. I think you should describe your app and the current situation in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ideal situation is that your app uses good MVC design and the majority of your view controllers don't need to be modified. If you're at that point, it should be relatively straightforward to update your current model(s) to use core data instead of plists. From my experience, it's kind of a pain to add Core Data support to an existing application, if your view controllers are portable and such, just create a new project that has core data support already.

The most important part is that you set up your core data model correctly relative to the rules you follow in your plists.

Comment: Using your hint, I found a great Presentation of how to accomplish this in iTunesU in "14.Core Data Demo (November 10, 2011)" by Paul Hegarty of Stanford.  it's a 1+ hour class.